# Executor finished with state KILLED exitStatus 1

Tags: apache-spark

After starting the master and a worker on one single machine...

```
spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master -i 127.0.0.1 -p 7070
spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker 127.0.0.1:7070
```

and submitting the following Spark job...

```
spark-submit --class Main --master spark://127.0.0.1:7070 --deploy-mode client /path/to/app.jar
```

the application is successfully executed but the executor is for some reason forcefully killed:

```
19/05/10 09:28:31 INFO Worker: Asked to kill executor app-20190510092810-0000/0
19/05/10 09:28:31 INFO ExecutorRunner: Runner thread for executor app-20190510092810-0000/0 interrupted
19/05/10 09:28:31 INFO ExecutorRunner: Killing process!
19/05/10 09:28:31 INFO Worker: Executor app-20190510092810-0000/0 finished with state KILLED exitStatus 1
```

[image: a]

Is this normal behavior? If not, how can I prevent this from happening?

I am using Spark 2.4.0.

Comment: did you manage to resolve the issue. I am having the same problem

Comment: No, I was not able to solve this issue unfortunately.