# All executors finish with state KILLED and exitStatus 1

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to setup a local Spark cluster. I am using Spark 2.4.4 on Windows 10 machine.
To start the master and one worker I do

```
spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master
spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker 172.17.1.230:7077
```

After submitting an application to the cluster, it finishes successfully but in the Spark web admin UI it says that the application is KILLED. It's also what I get from worker logs. I have tried running my own examples and examples included in the Spark installation. They all get killed with exitStatus 1.

To start spark JavaSparkPi example from spark installation folder

```
Spark> spark-submit --master spark://172.17.1.230:7077 --class org.apache.spark.examples.JavaSparkPi .\examples\jars\spark-examples_2.11-2.4.4.jar
```

Part of the log after finishing calculation outputs

```
20/01/19 18:55:11 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 finished: reduce at JavaSparkPi.java:54, took 4.183853 s
Pi is roughly 3.13814
20/01/19 18:55:11 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://Nikola-PC:4040
20/01/19 18:55:11 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Shutting down all executors
20/01/19 18:55:11 INFO CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Asking each executor to shut down
20/01/19 18:55:11 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
20/01/19 18:55:11 WARN TransportChannelHandler: Exception in connection from /172.17.1.230:58560
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

stderr log of the completed application outputs this at the end

```
20/01/19 18:55:11 INFO Executor: Finished task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1). 910 bytes result sent to driver
20/01/19 18:55:11 INFO Executor: Finished task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0). 910 bytes result sent to driver
20/01/19 18:55:11 INFO CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver commanded a shutdown
```

The worker log outputs

```
20/01/19 18:55:06 INFO ExecutorRunner: Launch command: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\bin\java" "-cp" "C:\Users\nikol\Spark\bin\..\conf\;C:\Users\nikol\Spark\jars\*" "-Xmx1024M" "-Dspark.driver.port=58484" "org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend" "--driver-url" "spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@Nikola-PC:58484" "--executor-id" "0" "--hostname" "172.17.1.230" "--cores" "12" "--app-id" "app-20200119185506-0001" "--worker-url" "spark://Worker@172.17.1.230:58069"
20/01/19 18:55:11 INFO Worker: Asked to kill executor app-20200119185506-0001/0
20/01/19 18:55:11 INFO ExecutorRunner: Runner thread for executor app-20200119185506-0001/0 interrupted
20/01/19 18:55:11 INFO ExecutorRunner: Killing process!
20/01/19 18:55:11 INFO Worker: Executor app-20200119185506-0001/0 finished with state KILLED exitStatus 1
```

I have tried with Spark 2.4.4 for Hadoop 2.6 and 2.7. The problem remains in both the cases.

This problem is the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56073438/executor-finished-with-state-killed-exitstatus-1) one.

Comment: check the executor logs you might be getting OOM error

Comment: If by executor logs you mean stdout and stderr logs, stdout is empty, while stderr shows no problems. I included the last 3 lines of the stderr.